# MIME type checking is enabled

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter

After running jupyter notebook on my cmd, it opens up a blank page.

I am getting these errors in my chrome console.

[image]

Comment: I get the exact same error. This happens when running `jupyter notebook` on any folder

Comment: The file "tree" that I expect is generated by jupyter is of `Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8`

Comment: Open issues reported: https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/537 https://github.com/jupyter/help/issues/538